# How to schedule execution of something more frequently then by the minute?

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, cron4j

Currently, using `cron4j`, i am able to schedule execution of an event at, say 13:01. While fine, from what i understand it does not allow one to schedule an event at 13:01:10 (10 seconds after).

Is there a tool that allows such granularity in scheduling?

Comment: Unfortunately using cron4j seems impossible. But you can do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26143988/450148

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a library, you should look into [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/quick-start). It is a very flexible scheduler.

Comment: And it can do sub-minute scheduling. Here's an example of [a schedule for running every ten seconds](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/cookbook/TenSecTrigger).

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can schedule task using Timer and Timer task class for example demo

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
public class MyTask extends TimerTask{
    Timer timer;
    int count=0;
    public MyTask(){        
    }
    public MyTask(Timer timer){
        this.timer=timer;
    }
    public void toDo(){
        System.out.println("count-> "+(count++));        
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        toDo();
        if(count>10){//this is the condition when you want to stop the task.
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

for this timer you can run this as follows

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     Timer timer=new Timer();
     MyTask myTask=new MyTask(timer);
     int firstSart=1000;// it means after 1 second.
     int period=1000*2;//after which the task repeat;
     timer.schedule(myTask,firstSart,period);//the time specified in millisecond.     
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long%29) class? It allows to schedule executions in regular intervals which are accurate to the millisecond.

Answer (score -1):

I **personally** find quartz a very complicated and strong scheduler so It's not easy to get started with quickly. It may not be an effective solution but you can `sleep(long)` before the execution of a task scheduled every minute.

```
public void execute(TaskExecutionContext context){
    sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMilliseconds(10));
}
```

**I haven't checked the syntax for the previous code so you might need to validate that.**