# SchedulingPattern con4j every 2 minutes 30 second or 150 seconds

Tags: design-patterns, cron4j

I have Scheduler use do run every 2 minutes. but i can't use to `2m30s`.Please help me

```
SchedulingPattern pattern = new SchedulingPattern("*/2 * * * *");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wait 30 seconds after the SchedulingPattern's start.

```
Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler();
scheduler.schedule("*/2 * * * *", new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Thread.sleep(30*1000);
            foo();
        }
    };);
schedule.start();
```